# /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight suddenly doesn't exist?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, intel

Been a few months since I've used my arch linux machine. I made a python script to alter the brightness values in `sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, but after coming back it appears this path no longer exists

```bash
$ sudo python brightness_controller.py increase                                                                                                                22:05:03
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mm/brightness_controller.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mm/brightness_controller.py", line 33, in main
    cycle_brightness()
  File "/home/mm/brightness_controller.py", line 13, in cycle_brightness
    current_value = int(open(brightness_file, 'r').read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'
```

Instead, only `apci_video0@` and `ascpi_video1@` exist

```bash
$ ls /sys/class/backlight/                                                                                                                                     
acpi_video0@  acpi_video1@
```

The folders seem to have the relevant brightness files to modify so I can just edit my python script to point there, but I'm puzzled as to how such a seemingly fundamental folder as `intel_backlight/` could cease to exist on my machine. I've done a few `pacman -Syu` system wide updates since, perhaps that somehow caused this?

What would cause something like this? How do core file system structures simply disappear / relocate?

specs:
machine: Asus M16 GU603
kernel: 6.1.7-arch1-1

Comment: `I've done a few pacman -Syu system wide updates since, perhaps that somehow caused this?` probably - I mean a few months ago you wouldn't have had kernel 6.1

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, I realized that this depends on whether I boot into my linux-lts or linux kernel. LTS still has the same `sys/class/` structure, while the normal linux has the new one.